# vscode vim extension doesn't work with other languages (e.g. Spanish)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

So I have installed vim extension for VSCode and I really like it, but when I switch my language from English to any other language extension stops working. When I switch back to English it works again. I use ubuntu btw

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way the *Vim* extension is built - it can't support any other languages (perhaps for technical reasons).

You can, however, make a suggestion or a GitHub Issue for a feature request.